# 301 Redirect in the HTACCESS working for all but a few pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So, I'm working on a site with 2 domains that are both hosted out of the same directory on the same server (It has Wordpress installed if that is important). I want to 301 redirect all the pages from oldname.com to newname.com with the same path. I have edited the HTACCESS and all but 3 pages are redirecting, but I can not find out why they are not redirecting.

Here's the code that I have to redirect, it checks the host and if it is not newname.com then it redirects to newname.com and maintains the path.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newname.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There's also a bit more code in the HTACCESS that was there before I added mine, I'll post it just in case it ends up being important.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule deflate_module>
    <IfModule filter_module>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml-dtd
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf font/opentype application/font-otf application/x-font-otf
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf font/truetype application/font-ttf application/x-font-ttf
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Here are the pages that aren't working (they should redirect to Irklaw.com/path):

```
http://muskokaattorneys.ca/home-commercial-real-estate-muskoka/
http://muskokaattorneys.ca/the-team
http://muskokaattorneys.ca/new-look
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The 3 pages are folders, without `/` ?

Comment: You also need to include the URL's of the 3 pages that aren't working. I think that might be more important to see since **those** are the ones not working.

Comment: They are not directories, they are just regular pages being generated by Wordpress like the other pages.

Comment: Did you try with other browser (to avoid cache problems) ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with various browsers and computers and the problem persists. I've posted the links to the pages so you all can see.

Comment: Not redirecting, but no name change at all in the url?